# Phonegap app don't show next page

Tags: android, jquery, json, wordpress, cordova

I trying to build an app with phonegap, jquerymobile and JSON (from wordpress json api). I use the code down here and that works for me it displays te list of recent posts (index.html).

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var wpAPI =  "http://myurl.nl/api/get_recent_posts/";

        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){
          $.getJSON(wpAPI, function(result) {

              $.each( result.posts, function( i, item ) {
                var html = '<li><a href="post.html?post_id='+ item.id +'"><img src="'+ item.thumbnail +'"><h2>' + item.title + '</h2><p>' + item.excerpt + '</p></a></li>';
                $( ".container>ul" ).append(html);

               }); 
               $("#list").listview('refresh');
           });

        });

     </script>
```

The problem is when I try to open one of the posts (post.html) the post.html doesn't show anything when I export the app for android.

So I think is something with refreshing, but maybe something else hope some can help me.

```
        <script>            

        function readSinglePost (url,container){

            var postId = window.location.search;
            var URL =  'http://myurl.nl/api/get_post/'+ postId + '';

            jQuery.ajax({
                    url: URL, 
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);

                        $('.container').html("<h3>" + data.post.title + "</h3>" + data.post.content + "");
                    }
            });

        }



        $(document).ready(function(){
            readSinglePost (URL,'.container');

        });     



     </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Replace 
<a href="post.html?post_id='+ item.id +'"> 
with 
<a href="post.html?post_id='+ item.id +'" data-ajax="false" data-role="none">

 function readSinglePost (url,container){

            var postId = window.location.search;
            var URL =  'http://myurl.nl/api/get_post/'+postId;
            jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: URL,
                    dataType: "json", 
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $('.container').html("<h3>" + data.post.title + "</h3>" + data.post.content);
                    }
            });
            return false;

       }
```

Comment: A part of this was the problem. It works from index to category but not from category.html to post.html i think there must be a reload (in te readSinglePost function) of something in the browser it works but not in the app

Comment: Add data-ajax="false" attribute in every anchor tag where you pass link by href. And chek this url 'http://myurl.nl/api/get_post/'+ postId + ''

Comment: the strange thing is i build it in coda and there it works but when i export it with build.phonegap.com and install it on my device it does'nt work. De list view (index.html) works and the link to all the category's also but only display a post don't work:( I shall add the complete html code

Comment: post it as new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593636/phonegap-jquerymobile-wordpress-post-not-appear

Comment: found the solution! the problem was that on the index.html and the category.html I used getJson and on post.html i used jQuery.ajax and i think there was a failure now i use only getJson and that's working!